# Undefined index when passing variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable from an html file, using jquery and ajax to a php file, where I want to process it. I have two test files:

ajax.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ajax</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link href="ajax.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#call_back").click(function () {
        $.post(
          "ajax.php", {
            value: $("#input_text").val()
          },
          function (data) {
            $("#response_text").val(data);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h3>Ajax</h3>
    <div class="entry-wrapper">
      <h4>Data to send to the server</h4>
      <input type="text" size="50" id="input_text" />
      <input type="button" value="Ajax Callback" id="call_back" />
    </div>

    <div id="response_wrapper">
      <textarea id="response_text"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax.php

```
<?php
    $value = $_POST['value'];   
    echo "Returned from the server: $value";    
?>
```

The html works fine. If I enter a value in the text field, it's passed to the php file, processed and sent back to be displayed in the textarea. 
I've looked in firebug and the post tag in the console shows the values that I enter.

The problem  is that I want to be able to use the variable in the php file, for arithmetic operations or running an sql query with it, but it shows up as undefined index when I open the php file.

I've looked through multiple threads on passing variables from jquery to php but still found no answer. I have no idea what the problem is. Suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use var_dump($_POST); to check if the POST is working

Comment: Well it seems your AJAX is working fine if you can pass the info back to the client. Where the problem in your PHP?

Comment: i used var_dump($_POST) and it returns array (size=0) empty and SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

Comment: i used files from a video tutorial and also tried the example from api.jquery.com relating to ajax with the same result

Comment: I've also tested a form submition where I entered a value in a text field and submit it to php. Used echo to display the value and it worked just fine

Comment: I've copy pasted your code and it works, problem is else where.. edit: (I just read the rest of your post hehe) what stopping you from using $value?

Comment: @Max So you can echo out $value without getting undefined index? Could it be a corruption within the server or php installed on my end?

Comment: Is value not by any chance a reserved keyword?

Comment: @Wray edit your post and roughly show us where and how do you want to use $value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you need to define the variable in your url. 
Example:

```
    http://yoursite.com/ajax.php?value=yourdata
```

This way when you open the file you are defining the value which is all you are doing with your ajax request. If this is not what you are trying to accomplish, try to rephrase your question.

Revised after 1st comment:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['value'])){
        //do whatever in here
       dowhatever();
    }

    function dowhatever() {
        $value = $_POST['value'];   
        echo "Returned from the server: $value";
        if(value == 'data') {
            //run query
        }//end if
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a way to pass a variable to php. But, I should have mentioned, I need to pass the variable when an event is triggered. For instance I have multiple divs and when I click on one, I want to pass the id or class or name of the clicked div and then in the php, process it, like storing it in a database, or retrieving something from a database that is connected to that div.

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you want with the data once you get it from the url in your php. You can check to see if the attribute is set in the url or if it is set to a specific value and run a function. In your function you can query your database or whatever you want.

Comment: Once you send data to the php file it will not store it automatically for you to use it later you need to do that by storing it in a database. To reuse the same value over and over again you can create a global variable on you JS file and set that to your value and every time you need it in php just send it again in your ajax.

Comment: I understand now. I've made the wrong assumptions when I saw the undefined index error when I opened the php file in the browser. I thought it wasn't working and I've also tested it wrong. I've written the value sent from ajax to a .txt file. It doesn't save the value when sending through ajax for later use, like Cedric explained. The code is just fine, it was user's fault, of course. Thanks a lot guys, you were really really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say you can confirm it's working, but when you directly open the .php file, it has undefined index, then I would say that makes perfect sense. If you are browsing directly to the .php file, then no POST data is being sent. But if you are able to type in some text, fire off the submit, and get text back as planned, then it's working.

Comment: I have another scenario in mind, Wray might also mean why he can't use $value on html page after it's been return )))

Comment: Right. But how can I access that variable in the php file and manipulate it

Comment: The same way you are accessing that variable now. 
$value = $_POST['value'];
So, when you submit it, it works right? You send text to the .php and get text back as planned? If so, then you are 'manipulating' the variable.

But as Max has stated, if you want to use it on the page, you'll have to do some Javascript voodoo on it.